# JS. Не правильное деление чисел

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Лог 1: Из вычеслений получается цифра -2

Лог 2: Длина массива 2

Лог 3: Деление -2 на 2 равно -1.666

Лог 4: Обычное арифметическое деление -2 на 2 = -1.

Как так получается? Почему цифры разные?

Comment: тип данных newVal проверить бы не мешало

Comment: Всё верно считает. Что происходит раньше - деление или вычитание?

Comment: ты про необходимость скобок забыл

Comment: @EOF читай: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: @МаксимНЕпихин прочитал. У деления приоритет выше, на что я и намекал.

Comment: @EOF Правильно. Ты берешь -2 делишь на длину массива 3 и потом отнимаешь 1. Если ты обернешь (получение длины массива - 1) в скобки, то получишь то, что хотел

Comment: @МаксимНЕпихин EOF - это не автор вопроса

Comment: @AntonShchyrov ой...

Answer (score 4):

Лог 2: Длина массива минус 1 равно 2. Отсюда длина массива равна 3

Лог 3. Делим -2 на длину массива (3) и вычитаем 1.

Answer (score 0):

`const equalSiblings = newVal / (siblingsInputsNotFocused.length - 1)` - ответ был в оборачивании скобок. Упустил этот момент. Спасибо xmikex